# Designing Django models with potentially horizontally growing data columns

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have many "features" that would be associated to certain real estate properties. For example, a Single Family Home can have 4 bedrooms, 2 bathrooms, 1 pool. An apartment unit will have air conditioning as well as a laundry room, etc. I am not sure how to correlate these features to each property in Django Models. My first attempt is to have each property be represented with a unique ID, and create one table with all the features listed? For example

```
propertyID | A/C | Bedrooms | Bathrooms | Electric Stoves | Pool | Balcony | Gas Stoves
123        | T   | 4        | 2         | F               | T    | T       | T
124        | F   | 1        | 2         | T               | F    | F       | F
...
```

As you can see, there are potentially lots of replicated values where if I am dealing with an area with lots of cold weather, `Pool` will most likely be all `F` in the way I chose to represent features. I am not sure of another way to model my data. The model will GROW horizontally as I add more and more features such as wifi, fireplace. It would also potentially could have many many `F` values for something really uncommon (helicopter landing pad)

example model in Django

```
class Features(model.Models):
  air_conditioning = models.BooleanField()
  electric_stove = models.BooleanField()
  pool = models.BooleanField()
  bathrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: I dont really see the problem with doing it this way. Possible thing you could think of... what if the A/C is only present in some of the bedrooms in one property? Maybe this is information is not needed, but this would not be possible with your design. In this case you would have to split your models, and have a seperate model 'Room' with columns like 'A/C' 'type' and so on. In addition, a 'Room' has a foreign key to the 'property' it belongs to. So a property becomes just a container for 'Rooms'.

Comment: if its growing dynamically in time i suggest you go with NoSQL DB's like MongoDB which enables you to overcome model migrations and dynamic columns creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the major issues with adding more and more columns is that the total number of columns in a single table is very limited. For instance, in MySQL there is a [hard limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html) of 4096 columns per table.

Another issue is that you need to modify database and applications schema every time you need to add a new feature (which means that you can't have user-defined features).

There is a number of possible approaches.

1. If you care about column count only and all these columns are boolean, you may try using a bitmap where every feature is a single bit. This way you have 32 features per 4-byte INT. This maps to ORM in a straightforward way, although you will need some bitwise boolean operations to get/set partcular features.
2. If you want to have thousands of columns or want to allow for user-defined features, you may consider using [Entity-Attribute-Value pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). You need to be aware of possible performance penalties though: should you wish to reconstruct the whole object with column per feature, you may have to run an expensive query. EAV per se maps to a single Model class which is in many-to-one relationship with containing Entity model classes
3. Modern databases support JSON/JSONB type where you can store nearly anything and utilize powerful queries. PostgreSQL in particular is known to have [good JSON support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). They are also available in DBMS from other major vendors.
   [JSON seems to be supported in Django](https://pypi.org/project/django-json-field/) as well
4. PostgreSQL-specific: [HSTORE column type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/hstore.html) which is essentially a map/dict works pretty well.

Comment: Very useful Synopsys @Dmitry! Thanks